# Windows Form asking .Net framework 4.5 while installing on Windows Xp sp3

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2013, installation

I have developed a Windows Form application in .Net C# using visual studio 2013. I am very sure that I have selected .Net framework version 3.5 while creating the project, so that it can install on Windows XP sp3 as well.

I have created the setup file using Visual Studio installer plugin. But when I have tried to install it in a machine which have windows xp sp3 with .net framework installed, there is an error showing that it is required .net framework 4.5 to run this application.

I have tried recreating the app, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could it be that your Installer itself requires .NET 4.5?

Comment: Is that be the issue? I donno about that much... do u know any installer which support .net 3.5?

Comment: @RishadAppat: usually, installers provide a set of criteria, which must be met to run installer. In particular, for .NET applications, these are minimal OS version and required CLR version. I've used VS setup projects a long time ago, but I'm sure, that these properties must be in setup project settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alryt.. I have figured it out myself...
Thank you dennis.. you gave me the clue...

It have to select from setup project properties--> Prerequisites...

that worked for me... :)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, right-click your project (not the solution, but rather the concrete project), go to properties, select the "Application"-ledger and check what is selected as Target Framework. You should be able to select .Net Framework 3.5 as build target.

Comment: Are all the references you use also 3.5? To check this Right-Click References in your project, select "Add References", and then look at the version field of all references.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Setup Project > View > Launch Conditions. Over here, it was already referring to .Net Framework, Right click on it > Properties, change the version to .Net Framework 3.5. It solved the problem.